# asyncronous Mysql.createConnection({})

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I need to create a mysql connection in nodejs , but the credentials for the mysql comes from a third party credential manager service. Can somebody suggest me a way to achieve this?

database.js - i am using connection from this file in all other database operations

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const {env} = require('./globals')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: env.DATABASE.HOST,
    user: env.DATABASE.USER,
    password: env.DATABASE.PASSWORD,
    database: env.DATABASE.NAME,
    multipleStatements: true
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error in DB connection");
        console.log("err", err);
    } else console.log("Connected!");
});

module.exports = connection
```

globals.js

```
const {getSecret} = require('../src/service')
require("dotenv").config();

async function getCredentials() {
    const result = await getSecret()
    return JSON.parse(result?.SecretString || {})
}

const credentials =  getCredentials() // not working, and i can't use await here
const env = {
    DATABASE: {
        HOST: credentials.ip_address,
        PASSWORD: credentials.password,
        NAME: credentials.dbname,
        USER: credentials.username,
    },
    SKU: process.env.SKU
}

module.exports.env = env
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 main options are:

1. Don't export `connection` but export an async function that returns a connection.
2. Write an `init()` function that sets up your database connection, and ensure it's one of the first things your application calls before anything else.

Comment: That helps!. do you have any reference or example for the second option?

Answer (score 1):

Well first, you need to fix up that `globals.js` file. Logic that depends on an async function must be async itself. You can just move everything into the async function like so:

```js
const {getSecret} = require('../src/service')
require("dotenv").config();

async function getCredentials() {
    const result = await getSecret()
    const credentials = JSON.parse(result?.SecretString || {})

    return {
        DATABASE: {
            HOST: credentials.ip_address,
            PASSWORD: credentials.password,
            NAME: credentials.dbname,
            USER: credentials.username,
        },
        SKU: process.env.SKU
    }
}

module.exports = { getCredentials }
```

---

And since even your database connection in `database.js` depends on this async function, it will have to be async as well:

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");
const {getCredentials} = require('./globals')

const getConnection = getSecret().then(function (env) {

    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: env.DATABASE.HOST,
        user: env.DATABASE.USER,
        password: env.DATABASE.PASSWORD,
        database: env.DATABASE.NAME,
        multipleStatements: true
    });

    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error in DB connection");
            console.log("err", err);
        } else console.log("Connected!");
    });
    
    return connection;

})

module.exports = getConnection
```

Comment: Thanks Skara. i will try this